# pandas rolling x days conditional cumulative count with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe which I wanna do rolling conditional count grouped by certain column

Input

```
col_groupby |  status  |    date
--------------------------------------
    A       | SUCCESS  |   2018-01-01
    A       | FAILED   |   2018-01-01
    B       | SUCCESS  |   2018-01-02
    B       | SUCCESS  |   2018-01-03
    A       | FAILED   |   2018-01-06
```

Output

```
col_groupby |  status  | status_cumcount | success_cumcount |    date
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    A       | SUCCESS  |        1        |        1         |  2018-01-01
    A       | FAILED   |        2        |        1         |  2018-01-01
    B       | SUCCESS  |        1        |        1         |  2018-01-02
    B       | SUCCESS  |        2        |        2         |  2018-01-03
    A       | FAILED   |        1        |        0         |  2018-01-06
```

`status_cumcount` : accumulates for every status grouped by `col_groupby` rolling by 1 day.
`success_cumcount`: accumulates for every successful status rolling by 1 day.

So in the fifth row there, count of status A in past 1 day is 1 with success status cumcount of 0.

How can I achieve this?
I tried:
`df.groupby('col_groupby').rolling('1d', on='date').status.count()` but it doesn't give the result that I expect.

It works however on numeric column. If I am trying to count amount like:
`df.groupby('col_groupby').rolling('1d', on='date').amount.count()`.
It will work.

Kindly help.

Comment: Could you clarify which is the expected output?

Comment: The input over there is the expected outpuut